# Deployment of play 2.2.3 application in glassfish 3.1

Tags: glassfish-3, playframework-2.2

I tried to build a war for play 2.2.3 application to deploy in glassfish server using play2war plugin. I followed the steps in
 https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/wiki/Configuration.
 But its not worked.

How to deploy play 2.2.3 application in glassfish server 3.1. Please help..

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be compatibility issue of Play 2.2.3 using play2war deployment on Glassfish 3. I get error as below:

```
Exception: java.lang.ClassCircularityError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Grizzly-kernel-thread(1)"
```

Sorry I do not know the fix, but using the same war deploys fine on Glassfish 4

For Play2War, it runs the best on Apache tomcat servers based on my simple tests

Answer (score 0):

To install play framework on glassfish (3 or 4) follow step by step the ssh codes:

- For glassfish home dir /your_path/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/

  1) Download and unzip glassfish:

  > ```
  >     unzip glassfish-4.1*zip
  >     rm -rf rm -rf glassfish-4.1.zip
  > ```

  2) Download and Unzip Play framework (jars)

  > ```
  > unzip play-2.2.6.zip
  > rm -rf play-2.2.6.zip
  > ```

  3) Extract it to your glassfish domain lib dir:

  > find play-2.2.6/repository/local/ '*.jar' -exec cp -vuni '{}'
  >   "glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/" ";"
  >       find play-2.2.6/repository/local/ -iname *.jar -exec cp {}   glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ \;
  >       rm -rf play-2.2.6

  4) Download new activator to create new application.conf file:

  > ```
  > unzip typesafe-activator-1.2.12-minimal.zip
  > rm -rf typesafe-activator-1.2.12-minimal.zip
  > cd activator-1.2.12-minimal
  > ./activator new sport-api play-scala
  > cd ..
  > ```

  5) Stop and start your glassfish

  > glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin stop-domain
  >   glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain

  6) Add custom variable to glassfish:

> ```
> glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin create-jvm-options -Dconfig.file=/your_path/sport-api/conf/application.conf
> ```

```
7) Done! Deploy your .war file using play framework features.
```

Obs: You can download this project "play 4 glassfish" with custom sh installer for glassfish 4.1. More features for future.
https://github.com/rbsdev/play4glassfish.git